# SQL Server: ALTER with ADD new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table

I have the following statement in SQL Server:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TruckTbl] 
ADD [TruckState] [bit] NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

What this will do is to default any NEW record to 0.

For existing records how can I get and say in the statement also default those to 0.

I know I can go and do an update but anyway to do within an update in the `ALTER` statement above?

Comment: Should your BIT field *really* be nullable? This basically makes it a tristate rather than a bistate. If that field did not allow nulls, all previous records would receive your prescribed default value!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [`WITH VALUES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) clause

```
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TruckTbl] ADD [TruckState] [bit] NULL DEFAULT 0 WITH VALUES;
```

Although I do agree with the other answer it seems odd that the column should be nullable at all if you are setting all existing rows to `0` and have a default for future inserts. Do you ever need to allow `NULL` as a column value here?

Comment: Cool, never knew *that* existed.

Comment: the only problem with this is that it will create an additional constraint in your table. You will need to delete it manually if you don't want to have this extra constraint, just be careful while deleting it because SQL Server Management Studio creates this constraint with a random name.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE {TABLENAME} 
ADD {COLUMNNAME} {TYPE} {NULL|NOT NULL} 
CONSTRAINT {CONSTRAINT_NAME} DEFAULT {DEFAULT_VALUE}
[WITH VALUES]
```

**E.g**

```
ALTER TABLE Temp
ADD ID int NOT NULL DEFAULT(1)
```

Comment: This is simple. Thanks.